# Android SDK in applications

Tags: android, api, sdk

How to find out the SDK version of an application. And, let me know the difference between SDK and API. Anyone Guide me to find out this.

Thanks in Advance,
SPK

Comment: http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find SDK version of a particular device by using below code :

```
 android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE

 android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT
```

Refer this for the difference between SDK and API :

http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/api-levels.html